# Удаление из списка в Python

Tags: python

[Код](https://repl.it/repls/BogusPowderblueCleantech):

```
lis = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
l = len(lis)
lis.sort()

for i in lis:
  if lis.count(i) != 1:
    print (i, end = ' ')
    for j in lis:
      if j == i:
        lis.remove(i)
```

В этой программе я хочу вывести числа, которые повторяются больше, чем один раз и мне надо удалить все повторяющиеся элементы, но когда я удаляю эти элементы, происходит перескакивание на след элемент и программа работает некорректно. Как мне это сделать?

Comment: можно и не удалять, а только считать их количество и если число повторилось 2 раза добавлять в set

Comment: @GGO считать не нужно, просто сделать из списка сет и потом опять список если надо.

Answer (score 6):

> но когда я удаляю эти элементы, происходит перескакивание на след
>   элемент

Потому что не рекомендуется менять список при его итерировании. Образно говоря, это как у машины при езде менять колеса.

Задачу поиска повторов можно, например, через [groupby](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) решить, а вместо удаления элементу, лучше создать новый список:

```
from itertools import groupby

items = list(map(int, input().split()))
items.sort()

new_items = []

for x, seqs in groupby(items):
    new_items.append(x)

    if len(list(seqs)) > 1:
        print(x, end=' ')

print(items)
print(new_items)
# 1 2 3
# [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5]
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

---

А если удалять элементы, то лучше это делать при обратном проходе, т.е. с конца, тогда при удалении элементов следующие индексы останутся актуальными:

```
items = list(map(int, input().split()))
# [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5]

for i in range(len(items) - 1, 0, -1):
    x = items[i]
    if items.count(x) > 1:
        print(x, end=' ')
        items.pop(i)

print(items)
# 3 2 1
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: @AK, получилось категорично, поправлю :) А так, удалять то можно, но лучше это делать с конца списка :)

Comment: Хорошо, но я один плюс уже поставил на ответе ) Люблю когда не просто дают ответ по делу, но и поясняют полезные штуки.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем конкретном случае проблема решается вот так:

```
lis=[1,2,1,3,4,7,2,6,9,4,5,7]
for i in lis:
  if lis.count(i) != 1:
    print (i, end = ' ')   
    for j in lis[::-1]:
      if j == i:
        lis.remove(j) 
print(lis)

1 4 2 7 

print(lis) # [3, 6, 9, 5]
```