# Цикл for, как удалить элемент i после его обхода(итерации)

Tags: python, for

Хотел вывести элемент i а после удалить его из итерируемого списка, написал следующий код как с pop так и с remove:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
for i in a:
    print(i)
    a.remove(i)

print(a)

b = [1,2,3,4]
for i in b:
    print(i)
    b.pop(b.index(i))

print(a)

вывод:
C:\python>1.py
1
3
[2, 4]
1
3
[2, 4]
```

Почему в обоих случаях цикл for не проходит по двойке и четверке? А просто перепрыгивает их?

Comment: Популярный вопрос

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1063123/%d0%a3%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-python